# How to modify sample in-app billing app to enable paid functions?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, billing

Let's say I provide 2-in-1 app: free and paid version. If user paid, then he gets additional functions available in the application.

To simplify the task and understanding, I took [sample application](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download). Then, I've added one more button to the main screen (this is our 'paid' function) - this button is disabled by default. If user paid for Potion (in the sample application), then this button should be enabled.

So, the following questions I have:

1. Which functions should be modified
   in the sample app to enable button
   once user paid? To simplify the task
   more, we can assume that user can buy
   only Potion, nothing more. Looks
   like it is not enough to add
   `myButton.setEnabled(true)` to
   `onPurchaseStateChange / if
   (purchaseState ==
   PurchaseState.PURCHASED)` only.
   Also, I need to have this button
   enabled after application start if user
   paid. Should I do it in
   `restoreDatabase`? Do I need to call
   this `restoreDatabase` in
   `onStart()` also?
2. The same question is about button
   disabling - where should I do this?
3. Once button is enabled, if user
   presses it, I need to verify that
   user really paid for the application
   (don't rely just on database value) - looks like I should call `RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS`. Then based
   on result either show warning and
   disable button, or allow further
   actions.

Comment: please share your code if you have any success with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of [AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary) simplifies the task.